# How to send View Object to ViewModel in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I want to send my View Object to my ViewModel, How can i do that in WPF MVVM.

Note:

Actually what i am trying to do is.. 
I have a MainWindow for which i am not following MVVM and this MainWindow has a Canvas in which i place all my views which are UserControls. 
Now from a Particular View called Stock i want to add a UserControl "another View" to the Canvas children on a Button Click from Stock View

Comment: You can't.  Not if you are following MVVM.  The ViewModel should have no knowledge of the View.  Can you be more specific with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually what i am trying to do is.. I have a MainWindow for which i am not following MVVM and this MainWindow has a Canvas in which i place all my views which are UserControls. Now from a Particular View called Stock i want to add a UserControl another View to the Canvas children. @cadrell0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view reference in your view model typically would be assigned on creation of your view.